# How to I append li's to a current ul using .load?

Tags: jquery, append, addition

I'm working on a search for amd I have the following line of code:

```
 $('#searchResults').add($('li:last').load(url + '&' + urlExtra));
```

This adds 10 li tags with content but rather than it adding to the ul it's nesting the last li with the loaded in list. To try and clarify i would like this outcome:

```
<ul>
<li>already in list</li>
<li>already in list</li>
<li>already in list</li>
<li>already in list</li>
<li>new li from load</li>
<li>new li from load</li>
</ul>
```

But i'm getting this:

```
    <ul>
    <li>already in list</li>
    <li>already in list</li>
    <li>already in list</li>
    <li>already in list
       <li>new li from load</li>
       <li>new li from load</li>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards
Rachel

Comment: jQuery has methods like `before` and `after` so if you found last `li`  you should add your `li` after http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead :

```
$.get(url + '&' + urlExtra,function(data) {
   $('#searchResults').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
})
```

`#searchResults` in my case is the `ul`. This uses [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add the new `li` to the end of the `ul`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `load()` function - *replaces* the content of the parent with the downloaded one. and in your code the parent of the load call is your last `li` and not the `ul`.  What you need is something that *appends* the content to the parent instead of replacing it. So theoretically, `load()` cannot do it for you. Use something like `.ajax()` or `.get()` to get the content and then append it to your parent `ul`

Comment: Does it actually replace the content? the API doesn't state this explicitly and based on the problem in the question it seemed to be appending to the already existing content. `already in list` is still there (though I don't know if this was just a label)
`<li>already in list
       <li>new li from load</li>
       <li>new li from load</li>
    </li>`

Comment: @nbrooks - in your code the parent to the load call is the last `li` (which incidentally ha the content 'already in list') - this is the `li` thats resolved with the `li:last` selector.

Comment: @techfoobar Right it's loading the new data into the last `li`, but the text `already in list` -- which was presumably there before -- seems to still be there after the new data is loaded

Comment: @nbrooks - ah. ok. now i see. That's quite strange. My understanding was that it'll clear the entire innerHTML of the parent.. I need to experiment this i guess. Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @techfoobar I was referring to the question above, not a prob that I'm having. I've never tried loading into something that wasn't empty, so I was just curious. I think you're probably right though, it might have just been a typo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to the last li, why don't you add it to the ul itself?

Answer (score 0):

try to append the new 'li' to the ul:

```
$('#searchResults ul').append("<li>asdasdasd</li>");
```

Comment: this works for the norm but I'm not loading static content, i need a mechanism to add content using the .load method.

Comment: $('#searchResults').add($('this selector is causing me issues').load(url + '&' + urlExtra));

Comment: you can append a empty li and update the content with load function, `$('#searchResults ul').append("<li id='someuniqueid'></li>"); $('#someuniqueid').load(url + '&' + urlExtra);` the return of the load will be only the content of the li

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$.get('foo.html', function(data) {
    $('#results').append(data);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="results">
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

**foo.html:**

```
<li>New item</li>
```

**Result:**

```
<ul id="results">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>New item</li>
</ul>
```